# Building VERY simple nested form with questions and answers in separate models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I've been working on learning to build nested rails forms and seem to be getting stuck on using separate models to store questions and answers.

In an attempt to figure it out, I'm trying to build a very simple app in which I have three models: `my_form`, `question`, `answer`.  For this app, I'm not using user authentication or anything like that, meaning that each form `has_many :questions` and each question `has_one :answer`.  This of course means that it's overkill to use separate question and answer models, but I'm trying to understand the most basic version of this sort of form nesting so I can apply it to more sophisticated situations.

So I have all my questions entered and saved to the database.  Its respective table has the following columns:

```
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| question_number  | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| question_content | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| my_form_id       | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at       | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at       | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My answer table is set up this way:

```
mysql> show columns in answers;  
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| answer_content | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| question_id    | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can easily show each question with my `show.html.erb` view:

```
<h1><%= @legal_form.title %></h1>
<p><%= @legal_form.description %></p>
<ul>
  <% @legal_form.questions.each do |question| %>
<li><%= question.question_content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

**My question is** how do I create an `answers.html.erb` view to match a simple text field to each question that writes to my answers table?

I realize that this increadibly simple and there are several gems that do this sort of thing and a couple tutorials out there that incorporate users into it.  I'm just looking for a basic example to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you rephrase the question? I'm not following how this is related to nested forms.

Comment: @Kimball Thanks for your response!  I'm trying to figure out how to properly create a view in which I can enter answers for each question on the form which saves to its own answers model.  Since I'm using separate models for questions and answers which would be referenced by a single view, I believe that would make this a nested form.  Is that correct?  Thanks again.

Comment: If you look at the following methods/Classes it will probably lead you in the right direction. View: [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for), Model: [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), Controller: [`StrongParameters`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). If you need the ability to add multiple answers then I would also recommend the `cocoon` gem.